# Single aspcore identity instance for multiple projects

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am currently working with a client and have been tasked to create a second app for the same client. The app will be web based (asp.net core) and since I have already completed one app for them using asp.net MVC with Identity framework (Boiler plate with some extensions) I would like for this new app in core to also use that identity instance, as some of the users will be accessing both apps. I know this is out there, but I have not found any answers or tutorials on how to accomplish this? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same Identity database for handling authentication and authorization.

Add an `ApplicationId` field to `AspNetUsers` table, derive from `UserStore` and re-implement the Find based methods so the queries take into account the `ApplicationId`

Every new application will have new applicationId in this case.

Also, you can separate the Identity database, so you decouple the authorization process which allows you segregate your application dependencies, add new applications easily in the future and scale as needed.

You can then use bearer token and web APIs. Once the user logins, you will pass the `username` & `ApplicationId` for the application that the user is requesting access, then your security service would return a bearer token if authorized and 401 error if not.

Comment: I have tried this, and I cannot seem to get the coding correct. The new app does not recognize the Identity instance in the database. Do you know of any tutorials I could check out that implement this?